# Google Authenticator - Showing someone my code

Tags: multi-factor

I want to create a video. During the video I need to login in to some website. I will use the one-time code from my google authenticator app. Is it safe to show this one-time code to the people or should I rather hide it?

Comment: You should be good as long as you are not live streaming the video

Answer (score 1):

It should be safe, as the OTP will change quickly (don't show it on live-stream though) and OTPs are designed in such a way that knowing previous ones does not allow you to figure out the next. I would still not recommended showing it if you can avoid it, just to be safe.